# Get time difference in milliseconds: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript. I'm trying to get the duration for a specific event in milliseconds. After some research I have simply created two **Date()** variables and bind it to **window** and got the difference. But I get the time difference as 0, which can't be true. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here? The relevant code snippet is given below.

```
case "discharge":
                window.timeStart = new Date();
                console.log("---A---===>>>" + window.timeStart);

                window.onload = function () {
                    window.timeStop = new Date();
                    window.timedef = window.timeStop-window.timeStart
                    console.log("---B---===>>>" + window.timeStop);
                    console.log("---DIFF---===>>>" + window.timedef);
                };

                //that.showLoadingIndicator();

                if (App.getInstance().getConfig().activeConfiguration == configurations.MultiFlow) {
                    that.currentProcessHandler = new measurementDischargeHandler();
                    window.onload();
                }
                else {

                    that.currentProcessHandler = new dischargeHandler();
                }
```

Comment: If it says 0, then it is 0. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Why do you think zero is wrong?

Comment: try using `window.performance`... it has sub-millisecond accuracy.

Comment: Because I want to see how long does it take to render a screen. So it can't be zero. It should be some milliseconds according to m understanding.

Comment: @Isuru: There is no "rendering a screen" between your two points of measurement in that code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmm...then I think I'm just being dumb. What I want to do is, once it get into the case "discharge" get the start time and once the if condition execute get the stop time and display the time difference.

Comment: There is also getMilliseconds() method that returns the milliseconds (from 0 to 999) of the specified date and time that you could use.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're getting the difference is just fine. You're **calling** `window.onload()` immediately after getting the `timeStart` value, see `***` comments:

```
window.timeStart = new Date(); // *** Getting the start

window.onload = function () {
    window.timeStop = new Date();
    window.timedef = window.timeStop-window.timeStart
    console.log("---B---===>>>" + window.timeStop);
    console.log("---DIFF---===>>>" + window.timedef);
};

//that.showLoadingIndicator();

if (App.getInstance().getConfig().activeConfiguration == configurations.MultiFlow) {
    that.currentProcessHandler = new measurementDischargeHandler();
    window.onload(); // *** *Calling* window.onload
}
else {

    that.currentProcessHandler = new dischargeHandler();
}
```

It's entirely possible (in fact, very likely) that no full millisecond has passed between when you get `timeStart` and `timeEnd`.

It's not clear why you're using `window.onload` at all, but that's why you're not seeing any difference in the time values.

---

Side note: There's no reason to assign properties to `window` in that code, just use local variables.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Found out that I was not calling it where it supposed to be called. Thank you once again :)